# Does Orange allow you to change the decision threshold in modelling widgets?

Tags: orange

I can't seem to find an option with the modeling widgets for Orange to allow changes in the decision thresholds.  Is this option available?

Comment: Not too sure myself, but you can check the (short) answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42354/how-to-change-the-threshold-value-in-orange), which suggests that it might not be too hard to create a workaround.